# Kubuntu 19.10: A ton of packages are set to autoremove (On a new fresh install)

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I just installed Kubuntu 19.10 and I went to go download Chrome. After it was done downloading, Kubuntu said I had updates, (which I intended to do when I first booted into Kubuntu) so I opened up a terminal and ran sudo apt update, then sudo apt upgrade. While that was running, I had opened up the google chrome image I just downloaded, and tried to install it (I knew it wasn't going to work until the packages were finished updating), and it said Waiting. So I waited a couple of minutes then the installer finally ran. I noticed that the log window wasn't creating new lines, so it was just this huge long line of text.  I noticed it was removing a lot of packages. So after it installed, I went to go run apt update, then upgrade, and low and behold, I see a FUCKTON of packages, waiting to be autoremoved.

https://files.catbox.moe/3uebvu.mp4

Remember, all of these packages set to autoremove, simply by installing chrome.

Im afraid to restart my chromebook so please respond as soon as you can, if you can.

Comment: Did you install Kubuntu from the standard Kubuntu Desktop .iso image? Or did you use a minimal image or netboot image or some other image?

Comment: Yeah I used the Desktop .iso image then I chose minimal installation in the setup.